# creating a new array with an element removed

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of elements, e.g. (apple, orange, grapes)

Say this is an array in a variable $fruit. I want to create a new variable $new_fruit, that removes the first element, $fruit[0]

I want to be able to do this

```
$new_fruit = unset($fruit[0]);
```

Of course I cannot, if I unset $fruit[0], then its removed from $fruit, and I need all elements to remain in the element $fruit. And create a new variable without the first element.

Comment: why not `$new_fruit = $fruit[0];` ?

Comment: ahhhh, `$new_fruit = $fruit` then use `unset($new_fruit[0])`?

Comment: Oh dear, a little bit too obvious for me.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the simple:

```
$new_fruit = $fruit;
unset($new_fruit[0]);
```

You can omit more than just the first one by changing the second argument:

```
$new_fruit = array_slice($fruit, 1);
```

Comment: the second argument, is the position of the element? And starting at 0?

Comment: Yes, and if you don't specify a length then it slices from that index to the end of the array.  So `1, 1` would give just index 1.

Comment: Or `$fruit, 1, 1` would give just index 1.